# PL/SQL: Conditional Where

Tags: asp.net, oracle, plsql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have the following scenario:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETINBOX
(
    inHasAttachments        IN int
)
AS

BEGIN

    SELECT M.MailId,
           M.SenderId,
           E.Emp_Name As "Sender",
           MI.RecipientId,
           M.Subject

    FROM MAIL M INNER JOIN MAILINBOX MI ON M.MailId = MI.MailId


    WHERE MI.RecipientId = '547' AND
          M.NotificationSelected = 'Y'

    IF inHasAttachments = '1' THEN
       AND M.Attachments = 'Y'
    END IF;


END GETINBOX;
```

Is it possible to add conditions to the where clause based on the value of a parameter?

```
    WHERE MI.RecipientId = '547' AND
          M.NotificationSelected = 'Y'

    IF inHasAttachments = '1' THEN
       AND M.Attachments = 'Y'
    END IF;
```

Obviously this is not allowed but is it possible to do this in some way in PL/SQL?
I know one way to do it is to duplicate the query and execute a different query based on the value of the parameter but I don't want to duplicate my code.

Comment: If the where clause is the only difference, then why not `UNION ALL`

Comment: Why do you mean by UNION ALL in this scenario?

Comment: ah sorry I misinterpreted the part on the use of the parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your requirements: if the value of parameter `inHasAttachments` is `1` then you want to filter further by `M.Attachments = 'Y'`, and if its value isn't `1` then you don't care about `M.Attachments`. This is in addition to the condition `MI.RecipientId = '547' AND M.NotificationSelected = 'Y'`.

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT M.MailId,
   M.SenderId,
   E.Emp_Name As "Sender",
   MI.RecipientId,
   M.Subject
FROM MAIL M INNER JOIN MAILINBOX MI ON M.MailId = MI.MailId
WHERE MI.RecipientId = '547' AND M.NotificationSelected = 'Y'
  AND (inHasAttachments <> '1' OR M.Attachments = 'Y')
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution, one thing I forgot to mention however is that I also wanted to add another "INNER JOIN" statement depending on some condition: IF (PARAMETER_VALUE = 'Y') THEN INNER JOIN MAILATTACHMENTS MA ON MA.MailId = M.MailId, IS THAT POSSIBLE?

Comment: Are you joining just to filter out more rows (those that aren't in `MailAttachments`), or are you joining because you want to select columns from `MailAttachments`? If it's the first then it may be doable but it'll start to look more and more like a hack. If it's the second (and maybe even for the first) then you may need to look at building the query as a string and using PL/SQL's `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: Thank you Ed Gibbs, building a query as a string and then using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is a great idea, it fits my needs considering I have too many conditions.

Comment: Good call - I just tried something similar to my answer above with an `INNER JOIN` and it got messy - very messy :)